# C# AutoCad Plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, autocad

I am using Autocad 2014 with C#. I need to create a partial CUI.
I reference to Kean code via [this link here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/05/creating_a_part.html) 
But it does not work as stated in the block.I encounter with follwing error.

> Autodesk.AutoCAD.Customization.FileSaveException: Write permission denied. Unable to create: 'c:\MicHydro.cuix' ---> **System.UnauthorizedAccessException**: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>          at Autodesk.AutoCAD.Customization.CustWrap.SaveToMenuPackageFormat(Boolean saveAll).
>   
>   Here is my code:

```
public class Commands : IExtensionApplication
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        BuildMenuCUI();
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
    }
    [CommandMethod("BuildCUI")]
    public void BuildMenuCUI()
    {
        const string myCuiFile = "c:\\MicHydro.cuix";
        const string myCuiFileToSend = "c:/MicHydro.cuix";
        const string myCuiSectionName = "MicHydro";

        Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;             

        string mainCui = Application.GetSystemVariable("MENUNAME") + ".cuix";

        CustomizationSection cs = new CustomizationSection(mainCui);

        PartialCuiFileCollection pcfc = cs.PartialCuiFiles;

        if (pcfc.Contains(myCuiFile))
        {
            ed.WriteMessage(
              "\nCustomization file \""
              + myCuiFile
              + "\" already loaded."
            );
        }
        else
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(myCuiFile))
            {
                ed.WriteMessage(
                    "\nCustomization file \""
                    + myCuiFile
                    + "\" exists - loading it."
                );
                LoadMyCui(myCuiFileToSend);
            }
            else
            {
                ed.WriteMessage(
                    "\nCustomization file \""
                    + myCuiFile
                    + "\" does not exist - building it."
                );

                // Create a customization section for  partial menu
                CustomizationSection pcs = new CustomizationSection();
                pcs.MenuGroupName = myCuiSectionName;

                //  add a menu group, with two commands
                MacroGroup mg =
                  new MacroGroup(myCuiSectionName, cs.MenuGroup);
                MenuMacro mm1 =
                  new MenuMacro(mg, "Cmd 1", "^C^CCmd1", "ID_MyCmd1");
                MenuMacro mm2 =
                  new MenuMacro(mg, "Cmd 2", "^C^CCmd2", "ID_MyCmd2");

                // Now let's add a pull-down menu, with two items
                StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
                sc.Add("POP15");
                PopMenu pm =
                  new PopMenu(
                  myCuiSectionName,
                  sc,
                  "ID_MyPop1",
                  pcs.MenuGroup
                );
                PopMenuItem pmi1 =
                  new PopMenuItem(mm1, "Pop Cmd 1", pm, -1);
                PopMenuItem pmi2 =
                  new PopMenuItem(mm2, "Pop Cmd 2", pm, -1);

                // Finally save the file and load it

               // pcs.SaveAs(myCuiFile);
                LoadMyCui(myCuiFileToSend);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadMyCui(string cuiFile)
    {


        Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices. Document doc =
          Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

        object oldCmdEcho =
          Application.GetSystemVariable("CMDECHO");
        object oldFileDia =
          Application.GetSystemVariable("FILEDIA");

        Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", 0);
        Application.SetSystemVariable("FILEDIA", 0);

        doc.SendStringToExecute(
          "_.cuiload "
          + cuiFile
          + " ",
          false, false, false
        );
        doc.SendStringToExecute(
          "(setvar \"FILEDIA\" "
          + oldFileDia.ToString()
          + ")(princ) ",
          false, false, false
        );
        doc.SendStringToExecute(
          "(setvar \"CMDECHO\" "
          + oldCmdEcho.ToString()
          + ")(princ) ",
          false, false, false
        );

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ==>  "Write permission denied."

Comment: looks like you don't have permission to save on c:\ (root)